# Этимология слова "испытуемый"

Tags: этимология, словообразование

Как образовалось это слово? Используется ли оно сейчас в своей исходной форме?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слово образовано от наименования действия (испытание) при помощи суффикса и окончания *прилагательного*: **-уем-(ый)**. При таком словообразовании обычно обозначается *возможность* или *допустимость* этого ***действия***. *(
Большой современный толковый словарь русского языка, 2012)*.

Слово "**испытуемый**" может использоваться для указания на людей, *подвергаемых испытаниям* в порядке эксперимента; в экспериментальной психологии оно используется без дополнительного существительного (аналогично слову "больной"). В технике распространено понятие "*испытуемые образцы*" (материала, изделий и пр.), которое указывает на образцы, *предназначенные* для текущих испытаний или *подвергаемые* испытаниям (нет жёсткой привязки ко времени "испытания", как у причастий; смысл - указательный). Слово "испытуемый" (используемое как существительное или прилагательное) в отличие от причастия "испытываемый", обычно не сочетается с дополнительными характеристиками действия "испытание", на которое указывает. Например, при конкретизации вида испытаний "на прочность" правильнее сослаться на образцы, "*испытываемые* на прочность". Отсюда следует, что понятия "**испытываемый**" и "**испытуемый**" далеки от взаимозаменяемости.